# What is the best way to receive location information at regular time intervals in iOS?

Tags: ios, background, location, cllocationmanager

I need to get the user location at regular intervals. e.g. every 5 minutes.

The application need to be able to do that while in background.

Giving the iOS restrictions that freezes the app conde while inactive I cannot have a thread/task running every 5 minutes to perform this task.

Using the Standard Location Service does not allow me to define an interval to receive the user location. Having it running all the time with the UIBackgroundModes=location will consume too much battery and be running at unnecessary times.

I have also considered using Significant-Change Location Service which has the ability to wake-up my app when a new location is available, but if the user is stationary no events are generated.

Anyone has any idea how I can accomplish this?

Perhaps another way to have a service waking-up my app every 5 minutes?

Comment: I looked into this sort of thing a while ago, I don't think its possible. What do you mean by a service waking up your app? There's nothing on the device that can wake you up, and an external server can't either.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Unfortunately, there's no way to do that in background state. You need to choose either the standard or significant-change location services. I hope Apple adds intervals to the standard location service in future.